# Single query to count by category by joining multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have the following 3 tables. I would like to write a single query to get a count of the number of courses enrolled in by a student for every difficulty level, and the total number of courses enrolled in as well. Students who have not enrolled should be listed too.

```
Students Table:
Student ID      Student Name
1               Alice
2               Bob
3               Charlie
4               David

Courses Table:
Course ID       Course Name             Difficulty Level
1               Arithmetic              1
2               Advanced Calculus       3
3               Algebra                 2
4               Trignometry             2

Enrollment Table:
Enrollment ID   Student ID      Course ID
1               1               1
2               1               3
3               1               4
4               2               2
5               2               3
6               2               4
7               3               3
```

Here's the expected output:

```
Output:
Student ID      Student Name    Total Courses       Courses with        Courses with        Courses with
                                Enrolled In         Difficulty Level 1  Difficulty Level 2  Difficulty Level 3
1               Alice           3                   1                   2                   0
2               Bob             3                   0                   2                   1
3               Charlie         1                   0                   1                   0
4               David           0                   0                   0                   0
```

I appreciate any help with this. I've tried a few different queries and am finding it hard to arrive at a single query that lists all students.

Comment: Then share your query attempts, show us some effort not just "do my homework".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  s.[Student ID]
,       s.[Student Name]
,       count(c.[Course ID])
,       count(case when c.[Difficulty level] = 1 end)
,       count(case when c.[Difficulty level] = 2 end)
,       count(case when c.[Difficulty level] = 3 end)
from    Students s
left join    
        Enrollment e
on      e.[Student ID] = s.[Student ID]
left join    
        Courses c
on      c.[Course ID] = e.[Course ID]
group by
        s.[Student ID]
,       s.[Student Name]
```

Comment: Thanks so much guys! Andomar and Matt, your queries worked great. The results are in a single row just like I needed.

Answer (score 1):

This will pull in all students regardless if they are registered for any courses or not

```
SELECT s.student_id, student_name, count(c.course_id)
, sum(case when difficulty_level = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as level1
, sum(case when difficulty_level = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as level1
, sum(case when difficulty_level = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as level1
FROM students s 
  left outer join enrollment e ON s.student_id = e.student_id
  left outer join courses c ON e.course_id = c.course_id
GROUP BY s.student_id, student_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, not exactly what you want but it is similar to what you want. Any knowledgeable person can help me to make this query to return result in one row. Conceptually i don't think my query will be able to retrieve required records in one row.

```
select s.id,s.name,
        count(c.id) as courses,
        case c.diff
        when 1 then count(c.diff) else 0
        end as "level1",
        case c.diff
        when 2 then count(c.diff) else 0
        end as "level2",
        case c.diff
        when 3 then count(c.diff) else 0
        end as "level3"
from student s
left join enrollment e
on e.st_id=s.id
left join course c
on e.cr_id=c.id
group by s.id,s.name,c.diff
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cec9/41)

As you can see in the fiddle that for "alice" for example, the courses information is coming in different rows. For course with difficutly level 1 there is an separate row and similarly for others.

Conceptually when sql engine is selecting the rows then it will encounter only one course info so that in a row it will give information for only one course.

Can anyone tell how to make the result come in a single row for a student ?

Comment: @MattBusche Then it will not return correct results. You can try it in fiddle.

Comment: you need to perform an aggregate function on your `level` columns, like Andomar and I did. See this fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cec9/49

Comment: @MattBusche : If you observe carefully then you can see that the result that you are getting is wrong. Student with id 1 has registered for one course of diff 1 and two courses of diff 2. And result shows in total user is registered for 5 courses which is wrong.

Comment: @MattBusche : i run your answer and it works fine. The minor mistake in the sql fiddle that you mentioned was it was returning 2 for level2 and 3 for level3 so that calculations were wrong otherwise it works perfectly fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.id AS 'Student ID', s.name AS 'Student Name', COUNT(e.c_id) AS 'No of cource', 

COALESCE(SUM( c.lavel = 1 ),0) AS 'Difficult lavel 1',
COALESCE(SUM( c.lavel = 2 ),0) AS 'Difficult lavel 2',
COALESCE(SUM( c.lavel = 3 ),0) AS 'Difficult lavel 3'

FROM students s 
LEFT JOIN enrollment e ON s.id = e.s_id
LEFT JOIN courses c ON c.id = e.c_id
GROUP BY s.id,s.name;
```

[image]